# How to avoid refreshing ng-repeat DOM list when array is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a front-end to a mail-system. It's nicely split up in controllers and services. I'm using $interval to check for new mails, which gets received in JSON, and added to a model.

Everything gets rendered nicely to the screen with checkboxes to choose mails for deletions and buttons etc...

The problem is, that while a person is making choices - $interval will check for new mails, and replace the model-array with the incoming data, recreating the DOM and resetting all choices no matter if it contains new or the same data. The whole idea of the front-end is to avoid a user clicking "update" all the time.

I thought angular.copy could save me from headaches, but no... I read up on all kind of weird stuff about including dates in your model to diff between the incoming and existing model.

I can only come up with one solution for this problem, and that is to write functions myself that compare the incoming and existing array with all existing properties on both object. Fx. obj1.id == obj2.id then check properties, or add object if it doesn't exist.

I have been spoiled rotten in Knockout, because it deals with these kind of things. (when sending the same JSON array to an observable it will not recreate the dom - leaving my checkboxes/dom changes, alone).

Does anyone have a good solution for this problem or can anyone recommend a hack of some kind? I'm open to everything! I'm beyond desperate.

Comment: how much overlap can there be? Surely you send something to API to define new query starting point ( last_id, timestanp, last_modified or whatever). Sounds like you need a `last_modified` field in each item's data and keep that synchronized with API on local changes. If user `last_modified` greater than version from API...leave local version alone and don't replace it

Comment: The REST webservices are already predefined. They accept the most a "range" of values to return. Like in Paginator for controlling a large set of returned values. Since its the model in the webapp which receives the returned information, it should take care of it. I think it's a bad idea to change all the webservices which work great, in order to tame a website.

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution!

After poking around and further checking the "track by" with my scenarios, I can see that it actually does more what it says:

1) If you have a collection of objects, with each object having: id, name, description, you can, using 'track by' choose a property that it connects to, so, on retrieving a new collection of objects from a webservice, it will not render the DOM object belonging to the value.

2) Most importantly, and what I was after: If an object with an existing id arrives from the server with fx a changed name, will it be reflected in the array collection on the object with that id? Yes, it will! So, "track by" will actually check the properties of the incoming object and replace the old object and still leave the id alone. That's intense.

It's also worth noting that "track by" works also with other directives than **ng-repeat**, such as **select**.

I made a small demo, for other people who might be confused about how everything works... but it seems to be cool!

```
    <div ng-repeat='country in countryArray track by country.id'>
        {{country.id}}
        {{country.name}}
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select ng-model='nonExisting' 
          ng-options='country.name for country in countryArray 
            track by country.id'></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KUf8C/

Comment: I see.  I was trying to solve a slightly different problem.  Here is a fiddle illustrating the problem I was working on http://jsfiddle.net/KUf8C/1/.  My solution might be better for something like tracking if an email has been read or not but for most other things including selecting items the track by solution seems better and is clearly much simpler.

Comment: Don't sweat it, I really appreciated your code. I'm no expert. It gave me some new ideas, and it was also quite humorous. A good way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS track by support on ng-repeat can help you here. By default it uses generated $$hashekey but this behaviour can be overriden. So if your records have unique ids you can use the track by to take care that the DOM is not reconstructed.

Ben Nadel did a post on this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm

Comment: Hey, yes I saw that, but from what I understand it only checks the id. What happens if the ID exists in the model but the new model coming in from the server contains fx an updated name? Then it should check both the id AND for changed properties. The id scheme is a step in the right direction, but will still leave me with some hacking to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an object to keep track of the selected emails.

Basically you keep a `selected` object in your scope and use it to keep track of which emails are selected.  For example if email 7 is selected then make `selected[7] = true`.

So in psuedoish code

```
selected = {}

user selects email 7 then selected[7] = true

selected == {
  7: true
}

user unselects email y then selected[7] = false

selected == {
  7: false
}
```

---

Here is a jsFiddle that I might have gotten a little carried away with. I use the technique described above to keep track of which emails are selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/8kY9u/11/

In the fiddle I keep track of new emails in a similar fashion too.

Comment: Hey Will, thanks for your time and effort :). It looks like what I'm interested in, however, from what I can see, the entire DOM will still refresh, however this time, the "selected" rules from the object will apply. While your example work, it seems as something that AngularJS should manage. It seems the only way right now, is to use that example Ben Nadel comes up with, although I don't consider it intuitive.